# Are there any safety concerns to have an current flow through a bronze wire that is connected to a copper wire?

Tags: current, ac

Are there any safety concerns to have an current flow  through a bronze wire that is connected to a copper wire?

Comment: "Connected" how exactly?

Comment: What sort of safety concerns do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Electrically, no there is no safety issue, not so long as they can both carry the applied current. That, and it meets safety isolation/insulation requirements.

Chemically you may set up and accelerate [galvanic corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion) which may cause the bronze to rot out before it's time, especially at the joint. That can cause an increase in resistance and subsequent overheating or burning out. How big an effect that is will depend on the make up of the bronze and which direction the current flows. Fortunately copper and bronze are fairly similar metals in this department so the effect should be a slow one.

Comment: Bronze and copper are fairly compatible, from the galvanic corrosion perspective.

Comment: that's because bronze is about 90% Cu, and Sn won't corrode, but certain bronzes can use Al.

Comment: Yes, there are many bronze alloys. The term "bronze" is almost meaningless, except that it means majority copper and something else.

Answer (score 1):

Bronze is not a good conductor compared to copper. If the wires are the same diameter, the bronze wire will have much higher resistance. This could cause the bronze wire to get hot. Apart from that, I can't think of any hazard that directly arises from using a mix of bronze and copper wire.